# Is there a way to know specifically the root free space (Android and iOS), using Apache Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, cordova

Recently I've been working on this topic at my actual job and all the researches went to this **availableBytes** function that you can see below:

```
function onInitFs(fs) {
    var appDirectory = fs.root;
    window.alert("Directorio de trabajo: " + appDirectory.toURL());
    availableBytes(function (free_bytes) {
    console.log("Interal free space(root + internal): " + (free_bytes / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)).toFixed(0) + "GB");
 });
}
//Function used to know available space in internal storage
function availableBytes(callback, start, end) {
     callback = callback == null ? function () {} : callback
     start = start == null ? 0 : start
     end = end == null ? 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 : end 
     //starting with 1 TB
     limit = 1024 // precision of 1kb
     start_temp = start
     end_temp = end
     callback_temp = callback
     if (end - start < limit)
         callback(start)
     else {
         window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, parseInt(end_temp - ((end_temp - start_temp) / 2)), function (fileSystem) {
              setTimeout(function () {
                 availableBytes(callback_temp, parseInt(parseInt(end_temp - ((end_temp - start_temp) / 2))), end_temp)
        }, 0)
     }, function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            availableBytes(callback_temp, start_temp, parseInt(end_temp - ((end_temp - start_temp) / 2)))
        }, 0)
     })
 }
}
```

As you can see, we can easily know the internal storage size, but the root one (that is where I store the downloaded videos and music and where the clients won't easily get to),cannot be "asked" so... Anyone know a proper way to do so?

Comment: dont know if it helps but when  you try to save a file and there is no space left  the request will fail with error code 10 (QUOTA EXCEEDED_ERR)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the available space of the device you have to add the cordova-file-plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/

Then after your device ready event you can run the following code:

```
cordova.exec(function(result) {
    alert("Free Disk Space: " + result);
}, function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error);
}, "File", "getFreeDiskSpace", []);
```

This will alert the total space in kilobytes, just  convert to megabytes or gigabyte.

Comment: It's a good answer but the free space given by this function is the internal storage, not the root storage that is where I'm going to store the content downloaded by the app.

What I've been thinking is to implement as Akis says:
* First I'll attempt to "write" a big file and if it gives error at the time of writing, I'll recursively call the same function until it gives an OK code, and that will be the free space of that specific storage space.

Comment: @DavidTelegimTv yes you are right, i also found a plugin that says it can do what you want but i never used it, its this one https://github.com/sqli/sqli-cordova-disk-space-plugin. If you have the time please check it